# How to set-up a dynamic grid to be two columns or one column based on page width?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have items that must either be aligned in two columns or one (media breakpoint defined -- mobile should be single column).

The order of the items is different between two columns or one.

The number of items is dynamic.

The size (height) of the items is dynamic.

An example in two columns might need to be:

```
left.one right.one
left.two right.two
left.three
```

Because the height is dynamic, the top of left.two might be above the top of right.two...

in one column it might align:

```
left.one 
left.two 
right.one
right.two
left.three
```

I can assign the one-column (or two-column) classes to the items dynamically when the items are rendered.

How can I set up a grid for this content *without needing to conditionally wrap the columns content when in two-column view* (ie, no outer div.left and div.right that must only be attached to the DOM when the content is two-column)? The problem with that approach is that it is JavaScript-dependent (I already have that solution). I want to solve this purely in CSS if possible.

I'm not going to post my working solution because, like I said, it depends on JavaScript to wrap each column content in an outer div when rendering two columns.

note: this is not the answer. this just *slightly* better illustrates the problem than the original demonstration

```css
:root {
  --gridColumns: 2;
}

.left,
.right {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--gridColumns), 1fr);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  :root {
    --gridColumns: 1;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left one">left one</div>
  <div class="right one">right one</div>
  <div class="left two">left two</div>
  <div class="right two">right two</div>
  <div class="left three">left three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as follows, this does require a change in the order of the grid-items as originally posted.

```css
:root {
  /* using CSS Custom properties ('CSS Variables') to
     simplify some aspects of the presentation update: */
  --gridColumns: 2;
}

.left,
.right {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  /* here we use the custom property defined earlier, introducing that
     property-value to the repeat() function via the var() function;
     the repeat() function defines the number of tracks along with the
     size of those tracks: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--gridColumns), 1fr);
}

/* using CSS media queries to update the custom property for
   display on devices using a screen with widths smaller than
   400px: */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   :root {
    --gridColumns: 1;
  }
}
/* for those devices with a screen greater than 400px in width: */
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .grid {
    /* we set the grid-auto-flow property to 'dense' in order
       to avoid empty cells: */
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
  }
  .left {
    /* placing all grid-items with the 'left' class-name into
       the first grid-column: */
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  .right {
    /* placing all grid-items with the 'right' class-name into
       the second grid-column: */
    grid-column: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left one">left one</div>
  <div class="left two">left two</div>
  <div class="right one">right one</div>
  <div class="right two">right two</div>
  <div class="left three">left three</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8zx3g57u/1/).

References:

- [CSS Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

Comment: not sure you have noticed, this solution does not fully resolve the issue. "The size (height) of the items is dynamic." was a requirement (so they can be different heights, I also originally said "Because the height is dynamic, the top of left.two might be above the top of right.two..."). set the height of .right.one to 100px -- you'll notice that .left.one is forced to grow as well.

Comment: if you then also set the height of .left.one to 50px, there's a bunch of undesired space between left.one and left.two

Comment: That is one of the problems of CSS grid, unfortunately; what would you like to happen in those scenarios?

Comment: they should maintain the margins, so the column heights should vary

Comment: Hi, you may probably want to check this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390046/8620333 .. we are actually only 2 CSS guys *fighting*. We probably need more opinions. Thanks